# Using Network Resources for currency converter

Tags: java, android, android-networking

I have gone through the tutorials of using network resources in android. But I was not satisfied. What I am looking for is an way to get inside the webpage. The tutorials tell how to get to an URL. Well that is pretty simple as far as I can tell.

I am trying to make an currency converter app and for that I will have to get the exchange rates. How to do that exactly? [This](http://www.oanda.com/currency/converter/) webpage gives an decent amount of exchange rates. I want to use this in my app. How can I do it?

Example-User selects an "from" and an "to" currency in the app. And that conversion should happen instantaneously. So for that I will have to get the exchange rates before hand and store them in the database. And If the user is offline,the app should select the last updated values.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an API; like this free open source one: http://josscrowcroft.github.com/open-exchange-rates/ to get the currency exchange rate as it would be impossible or at least extremely difficult to parse the data from the url you provided.

The API I suggested above will give you the rates you need back in JSON format which can be easily parsed in java.

Comment: this solution works for this use case, but I think a more general answer would be useful for the OP later in a different use case!

Comment: I really dont know anything about JSON but I studied tons of tutorial. Still dont understand a thing. Could you please tell me how exactly to extract the information from [here](https://raw.github.com/currencybot/open-exchange-rates/master/latest.json) and store it in an array,say a 2D String array?